# Can anyone please explain me the functioning of standard scalers in python sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I read about them and found that, they basically scale up the values.So dont they change up the values of the records? ok if they scale up/down the values,so there graph must look same everytime,but i saw changes in the graph as per selection of scaler.Please let me know this as I am new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standardizing the features around the center and 0 with a standard deviation of 1 is important when we compare measurements that have different units. Variables that are measured at different scales do not contribute equally to the analysis and might end up creating a bais.However, the minimum and maximum values vary according to how spread out the variable was, to begin with, and is highly influenced by the presence of outliers.

For example, A variable that ranges between 0 and 1000 will outweigh a variable that ranges between 0 and 1. Using these variables without standardization will give the variable with the larger range weight of 1000 in the analysis. Transforming the data to comparable scales can prevent this problem. Typical data standardization procedures equalize the range and/or data variability.

Note in particular that because the outliers on each feature have different magnitudes, the spread of the transformed data on each feature is very different.`StandardScaler` cannot guarantee balanced feature scales in the presence of outliers.

As you saw changes in the graph as per selection of scaler, one resion can you used StandardScaler() to standardize data so far doesn't work with NaNs (missing values).It's not exactly that simple to deal with NaN values. It requires analyses of the data before taking any further step to deal with the NaN values. There are various ways you can deal with these missing values (the following is not an exhaustive list):

- **Ignore missing values altogther :** the problem with this approach is that the missing rows might contain important information in other
  columns and ignoring them would lead to incomplete analyses
- **Replace them with another value :** this one of the commonly used approaches, but the choice of the value that you will use to replace
  will affect your overall analysis. You could replace them with say
  mean, or say a placeholder value (like -1) which you know never
  occurs throughout the column.
- **Using regression to substitute the values**
- **Using KNN to substitue values **